# How to create grid button(2*2) on iphone.

Tags: iphone

I want to create a grid of buttons 2*2 programatically.

How can i do this?

Comment: This is a bit overly broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no code in the question I will explain how to do it for any size grid not just 2*2.

Buttons can be laid out by their frame value right? So create buttons in 2 `for` loops, 1 loop for rows another for columns. You can then adjust the `x` origin of all buttons in the first row and the `y` origin will stay the same. Once you get to the second row you will adjust the `y` origin once, then adjust the `x` origin for each button in that row.